# How does this PNP transistor and P-channel MOSFET circuit work?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, pnp

How does this PNP and P-channel MOSFET circuit work? How does the current flow? What are the voltage potentials at the nodes A, B, C and D?

[image]

Comment: ipving - Hi, Since you're asking about it, it seems that isn't your design. Therefore please can you [edit] the question and add the [required](/help/referencing) source name & link for that schematic. Thanks.

Comment: That's a P-channel MOSFET.

Comment: @samgibson: It's from a german video on youtube

Comment: Perhaps tell us what you know so we know where to start - would I be right to think you’re familiar with n-channel FETs and NPN bipolars?

Comment: @ipving - Hi, You said that the schematic is "*from a german video on youtube*" - So please add a link to that video into your question (and, ideally, with the timestamp where that schematic is shown, or at least mention the actual timestamp in words). Thanks.

Comment: @ipving - Hi, You posted an answer to say thank you. Although that's appreciated, Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums (please see the [tour] & [help]). An *answer* cannot be used in that way, so it was deleted, sorry. Please see the article in the [help] called: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers)" & follow that guidance. If your question has been solved, consider upvoting useful answers & [áccepting](/help/accepted-answer) your choice of best answer. Or if you need clarification on an answer, you can comment below it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First consider the circuit without Q4. What remains is Q2, R1 and R2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fixpBe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With Q2 being a P-channel device, gate potential (\$V_C\$ at node C) must be significantly *lower* than its source (\$V_B\$ at node B) in order for the transistor to be "on". That is, if gate potential \$V_C\$ at node C is close to the +14V supply, the potential difference \$V_{GS} = V_C-V_B\$ (between the transistor's gate and source) is near zero (or maybe even positive), and Q2 is switched off, blocking current \$I\$.

Conversely, when \$V_C\$ is near 0V, as is the case shown above, \$V_{GS}\$ is at a maximum (most negative, that is), and Q2 is on, passing current unimpeded.

What you need, then, to control current through Q2 is a way of causing the potential \$V_C\$ to *rise* when current \$I\$ *exceeds* some required limit, switching Q2 off. When \$I\$ is below that limit, you would want the potential \$V_C\$ to be nearer zero, to switch Q2 on.

That's the job of Q4, with the help of R1 and R2. In isolation they look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwQvQa.png)</sup>

Current \$I\$ is simulated by source I1, and is drawn via R1. This causes a voltage \$V_A - V_B\$ to develop across R1, according to Ohm's law. A PNP BJT will begin to conduct between emitter (A) and collector (C) when the base-emitter potential difference \$V_B - V_A\$ (usually referred to as \$V_{BE}\$) reaches −0.6V or so.

Therefore, if sufficient current \$I\$ flows through R1, the base-emitter potential difference \$V_{BE}\$ will reach \$V_B-V_A=-0.6V\$, and Q4 will quite suddenly begin to conduct current down through R2. The result is that the potential \$V_C\$ rises sharply as the voltage \$V_{BE}\$ across R1 exceeds 0.6V, reaching close to +14V near \$V_{BE}=0.7V\$.

The current through R1 required to achieve 0.7V across it is, corresponding to a maximum \$V_C\$:

$$ I = \frac{V_{R1}}{R_1} = \frac{0.7V}{10\Omega} = 70mA $$

In other words, as \$I\$ approaches 70mA, \$V_C\$ will reach a maximum. This can be seen in a simple simulation, in which I sweep current \$I\$ from zero to 200mA, and plot the resulting values of \$V_A-V_B\$ and \$V_C\$:

[image]

Q4, R1 and R2 together provide a gate potential \$V_C\$ which rises if the 70mA current limit is approached, which would cause MOSFET Q2 to switch off. It wouldn't switch off completely, because that would bring current to zero, which would cause \$V_C\$ to fall again, and switch Q2 back on. In practice such negative feedback causes a stable equilibrium to be established, where current is capped at 70mA:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCmx2E.png)</sup>

The region in red is a variable load, which would like to draw anywhere from zero amps upwards, depending on source V1. Watch what happens as I sweep V1 upwards, drawing more and more current:

[image]
[image]

We see here that the current is limited to a maximum of 70mA, since that's where Q4 is fully on, \$V_C\$ is highest, and Q2's drain-source channel is being throttled.

Your own circuit has a dead short from Q2's drain to ground (0V), which we can simulate with a ammeter to measure the resulting current. If you've grasped what I said above, you can see why current will flow, but will be "stuck" at a 70mA maximum:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsNKim.png)</sup>

---

In your own circuit, and in the schematic immediately above, node D is connected directly to ground. Its potential is always 0V, irrespective of anything else.

In my third schematic, however, the one with the load in the red box,  that direct connection is lost, and node D is able to adopt potentials other than 0V. The upper limit to potential \$V_D\$ is determined by the maximum voltage "lost" across R1, which is constrained to be less than 0.7V for two reasons:

1. Q2's base-emitter junction is a diode, which will clamp the potential difference across it to a maximum of 0.7V.
2. When the current limiting behaviour of this circuit kicks in, current \$I\$ is actively prevented from exceeded that limit, so even if Q2's base-emitter junction diode wasn't clamping, the current through R1 still couldn't rise enough to cause the voltage across it to exceed 0.7V.

In short, the voltage across R1 cannot exceed 0.7V, and node B cannot ever have a potential lower than:

$$ V_{B(MIN)} = V_{CC} - V_{R1(MAX)} = +14V-0.7V = +13.3V $$

This same constraint is imposed at D, which can never be greater than +13.3V, but can have any potential between 0V and +13.3V. The actual value of \$V_D\$ depends on the load. Take a look at three scenarios in which I place a light load, a moderate load, and an excessive one respectively:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdRovd.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXON5E.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6aOQU.png)</sup>

In the last two I chose load R3 to be 100Ω and 5Ω respectively. In both cases the load is heavy enough to invoke current limiting at 70mA, and with Ohm's law we can calculate the voltages across R3 that would result from them passing 70mA:

$$ V_{R3B} = 70mA \times R_{3B} = 70mA \times 100\Omega = 7V $$
$$ V_{R3C} = 70mA \times R_{3C} = 70mA \times 5\Omega = 0.35V $$

These values do not exceed the maximum +13.3V "compliance voltage" of our current source, and the source can indeed "comply" with the full 70mA.

Now consider the load of 300Ω. If 70mA were to flow through that resistance, by Ohm's law the required voltage across it would be:

$$ V_{R3A} = 70mA \times 300\Omega = 21V $$

This exceeds the maximum available at D by some margin, and the current source is unable to comply. It does the best it can under these circumstances, which is to supply the greatest voltage available, in this case a little over the calculated maximum of \$V_D = 13.3V\$.

Answer (score 2):

It's a current source. The wire from the drain to GND is virtually a short circuit, but it's current is limited to 0,6V/R1. I bet it would often be more useful to have some load instead of a wire. But also a circuit which sinks a certain current and dissipates the energy has some usage.

If there were higher Id the transistor would short the mosfet gate-source voltage which is fed to the gate through R2. The basic idea of using a bipolar transistor to see the voltage over a current sensing resistor is at least 60 years old. It has been used even in voltage regulator ICs for current limiting.

Answer (score 0):

AS already pointed out, it is a "current" source ...  unless R3 < 200 Ohm.
The current value is  ~ 10/160 = 0.0625 A.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Arranging the circuit so as to be more understandable and easier to analyze, although constants are missing, from an analysis by inspection I obtain:[image]

Answer (score -2):

In principle, it is nothing else than a classical amplifier stage in common-emitter configuration - however, with a pretty uncommon feedback circuitry, controlled by the collector voltage.

Comment: Actually, it is a constant-current regulator with the Q1 base-emitter voltage acting as the reference.  Unlike a classic(al) amplifier stage, it has no external input signal that controls the output.  The output current is adjusted by varying the value of R1.  Overall, the circuit is less like an amplifier and more like a two-terminal device - a constant-current diode.